# How to pass a value to an anonymous function?

Tags: php, silex

The method below does not work.

```
$dir = '/web/source/htm/arc.php'

// no routing
$app->get('/', function() {
    return ob(__DIR__ . $dir);
});
```

In JavaScript, $dir ( of course in JS syntax ) would be accessible by the function, but in PHP it does not seem to work.

I also tried

```
// no routing
$app->get('/', function($dir) {
    return ob(__DIR__ . $dir);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous functions are also known as closures in PHP.  This is similar to JavaScript closures, except that the enclosed variables are not created automatically.

This saves memory by not implicitly importing variables you do not need.

You must explicitly import these variables using the `use` keyword.

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($dir) {
    return ob(__DIR__ . $dir);
});
```

See here:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 4):

In PHP variables outside a function are not accessible inside (with the exception of [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variables).

In order to get access to variables outside the scope of a function you have to tell the function that it should have access to it. That is done using the `use` keyword:

```
$dir = '/web/source/htm/arc.php'

// no routing
$app->get('/', function() use ($dir) {
    return ob(__DIR__ . $dir);
});
```